# UITableViewRowAction: Delete

Tags: uitableview, swift, xcode6

I want to let the user to be able to delete a table cell at the moment I have the delete swipe action but I don't know how to actually delete the selected cell! As you can tell I am programming in Swift and Xcode 6.3.1

```
var deleteAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Default, title: "Delete") { (action, indexPath) -> Void in
            tableView.editing = false
            println("deleteAction")
            }
```

Here is screenshot on dropbox as well: [Screenshot Of Delete Swipe Action](https://www.dropbox.com/s/eq5xk9k5fefx8tw/iOS%20Simulator%20Screen%20Shot%206%20Jun%202015%2011.09.40.png?dl=0)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to remove a cell completely from tableView then you have to remove it from your table Array too. Consider below code:

```
var deleteAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Default, title: "Delete") { (action, indexPath) -> Void in
        tableView.editing = true
            // Remove it from your TableArray and If it is stored into any local storage then you have to remove it from there too because if you doesn't remove it from your local storage then when you reload your tableview it will appears back

            self.tableData.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row) 

            tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)

    }

    return [deleteAction]
}
```

Comment: This one worked, I had some errors with my array but that was because it was a let not a var! Thanks though!!

Answer (score 1):

This might help you.

```
  func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete) {
        // handle delete (by removing the data from your array and updating the tableview)
        if let tv=tableView
        {
         items.removeAtIndex(indexPath!.row)
            tv.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)

    }
}
```

Comment: When I add it into commit Editing Style and add my own array of items (which is 'products') I get an error of 'Immutable value of type '[String]' only has mutating members named 'removeAtIndex'' @RandomBytes

Comment: try what Dharmesh Kheni suggested, it might be the solution. I am too hungover to really help much more then this lol. Goodluck.

Answer (score 1):

You must implement `editActionsForRowAtIndexPath` and `commitEditingStyle`

```
- (NSArray *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editActionsForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    __weak SampleViewController *weakSelf = self;

    UITableViewRowAction *actionRed =
    [UITableViewRowAction
     rowActionWithStyle:UITableViewRowActionStyleNormal
     title:@"Delete"
     handler:^(UITableViewRowAction *action, NSIndexPath *indexPath) {
         NSLog(@"Delete!");

         [weakSelf.itemsList removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
         [weakSelf.tableView setEditing:NO animated:YES];
         [weakSelf.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath]
                                   withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];

     }];

    actionRed.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.844 green:0.242 blue:0.292 alpha:1.000];


    return @[actionRed];
}


/*
 * Must implement this method to make 'UITableViewRowAction' work.
 *
 */
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

}
```

Here is an example [ActionRowTest](https://github.com/vanyas/ActionRowTest)